# Regex take part of string after another part

Tags: regex

I want to take second part of string that is after another using regex.For example the string is foo-bar i need the bar.I have tried to find in google but nothing comfortable.

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. What regex patterns have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yourPrefix([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

Matches any alphabetic/numeric characters after 'yourPrefix'

For your example data in javascript:

```
  '[BBSHORTCODE_LINK'.match('BBSHORTCODE_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)').pop() //'LINK'
'[BBSHORTCODE_BUTTON'.match('BBSHORTCODE_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)').pop() //'BUTTON'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String example = “foo-bar”;
String[] splitResult = example.split(”-“);
```

splitResult[1] would be your "bar"

Comment: No its not that, i need to take last part of string look real example in [BBSHORTCODE_BUTTON i need BUTTON, [BBSHORTCODE_LINK i need LINK etc.

Comment: String example = "foo-bar-email-address";
String[] splitResult = example.split("-");
System.out.println(splitResult[splitResult.length - 1]);

Will give you "address" (it is the last part of it)